# Issues In Splash Screen with progressDialog

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

My Issue is progress Dialog not display with the splash Screen?Can Any one solve this, Any help could be appreciated thanks in advance !

```
public class Splash extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                sleep(3*1000);
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressDialog.setMessage("wait");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };thread.start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

 ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressDialog.setMessage("wait");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                sleep(3*1000);

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
 progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };thread.start();

}

}
```

Comment: Actually i want spinner rotating style there is no dilaog boxes with that spinner only spinner appeared then how @Nirav

Comment: Use preogressbar library

Answer (score 0):

Cuz you are updating the UI in background thread.. 
try to use the

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable.......)`

or try to put the UI work on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Everthing you write inside a thread will be executed in background. you **can't manipulate any UI elements from a background Thread**. you should be getting an error from this code, check your stacktrace. I suggest you remove the code for the ProgressDialog from the Thread and put it before the Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should show the progress dialog from UI thread. Or you can use runOnUiThread(...) method. If you have to show it from a different thread write thin inside run method of thread:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //add try catch
        sleep(3*1000);
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
});
```

I would suggest using handlers instead of sleep in your activity. You can also try this without the thread in your code:

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
h.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressDialog.setMessage("wait");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        },
        (3*1000));
```

Comment: it continously showing progressdialog it doesnt goes to mainactivity when i m using handler @drulabs

Comment: You have to add startActivity code and dialog.dismiss() wherever you need in your app.

Comment: As you can see in the handler example, there is only show() for progress dialog there is no dismiss. You need to include dismiss as per your requirement.